# Problem with QGIS and Keras

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm developing a plugin in QGIS using the Keras' library for deep learning.

I have some problems when I load and save the model.

The **error** is the following:

> File "h5py/h5p.pyx in h5py.h5p.PropFAID.set_libver_bounds
>                ValueError: Invalid high library version bound (invalid high library version bound)

Comment: Please include the code you used that produced this error.